# Is there a nice way to "repackage" keyword args in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, keyword-argument

I have several methods that take many (keyword) arguments that end up passing the same set of arguments along to another method.

The following is normal.

```
def foo(a:, b:, c:, d:, e:)
  bar('var', a:a, b:b, c:c, d:d, e:e)
end

# takes the same arguments as #foo + one more
def bar(var, a:, b:, c:, d:, e:)
  ...
end
```

This is just kind of tedious and annoying.  I'm wondering if there is anything in the Ruby core that would make it easy to do the following...

```
def foo(a:, b:, c:, d:, e:)
  bar('var', <something that automagically collects all of the keyword args>)
end
```

I know that you can parse over `method(__method__).parameters`, do some gymnastics, and package everything up into a hash that could be double-splatted and passed to `bar`.  I'm just wondering if there is already something in the core that does that in a nice, neat way?

If there is something that applies in a more general way, i.e. not only to keyword args, then that's certainly interesting too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [`**args` will gather arbitrary keyword arguments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) as a Hash. Use ** again to flatten the Hash into keyword arguments for `bar`, Ruby 3 will no longer do this for you.

```
def foo(**bar_args)
  # The ** is necessary in Ruby 3.
  bar('var', **bar_args)
end

def bar(var, a:, b:, c:, d:, e:)
  puts "#{var} #{a} #{b} #{c} #{d} #{e}"
end
```

This is appropriate if `foo` never uses those arguments, it just passes them along to `bar`. If `foo` were to use some arguments, those should be defined in `foo`.

```
def foo(a:, **bar_args)
  puts "#{a} is for a"
  bar('var', a: a, **bar_args)
end

def bar(var, a:, b:, c:, d:, e:)
  puts "#{var} #{a} #{b} #{c} #{d} #{e}"
end
```

Comment: Yup, that's the kicker...not ever using `bar_args` in `foo`.  I've plowing through some gross stuff and trying to clean it up.  I've been faced with situations where `foo` was doing things with the values passed inside `bar_args`.  I decided that was smelly code and ripe for some refactoring....

Answer (score 0):

I got a nice way:

```rb
def foo(a:, b:, c:, d:, e:)
  args = {a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d, e: e}
  bar('var', **args)
end

def bar(var, a:, b:, c:, d:, e:)
  ...
end
```